# spurious network error (2 tries remaining): [7] Couldn't connect to server

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, substrate

```
gh@ubuntu:~/substrate-node-template$ CARGO_HTTP_MULTIPLEXING=false cargo build --release
    Updating crates.io index
warning: spurious network error (2 tries remaining): [7] Couldn't connect to server (Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Connection refused); class=Net (12)
warning: spurious network error (1 tries remaining): [35] SSL connect error (OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection reset by peer in connection to github.com:443 ); class=Net (12)
error: failed to get `frame-benchmarking` as a dependency of package `node-template v3.0.0 (/home/gh/substrate-node-template/node)`

Caused by:
  failed to fetch `https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index`

Caused by:
  network failure seems to have happened
  if a proxy or similar is necessary `net.git-fetch-with-cli` may help here
  https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html#netgit-fetch-with-cli

Caused by:
  [28] Timeout was reached (Operation timed out after 30001 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received); class=Net (12)
```

The above error occurred when I compiled
I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 , substrate 3.0.0

My rust version:

```
gh@ubuntu:~/substrate-node-template$ rustup show
Default host: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
rustup home:  /home/gh/.rustup

installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

active toolchain
----------------

stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
rustc 1.50.0 (cb75ad5db 2021-02-10)
```

I try to add "cargo" before "cargo build - relax"_ HTTP_ Multiplexing = false "and execute.
But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a substrate question.

Try to use a VPN. Or use a mirror source.